# Wordpress: Trigger a function when a new post published

Tags: wordpress, function, post

I want a function that triggers when a new WordPress post publish.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
function post_published_notification( $post_id, $post ) {
    $author    = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
    $name      = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
    $email     = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title     = $post->post_title;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
    $edit      = get_edit_post_link( $post_id, '' );

    $to[]    = sprintf( '%s <%s>', $name, $email );
    $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );

    $message   = sprintf( 'Congratulations, %s! Your article "%s" has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message  .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

I tried this one. I tried also different statuses such as `save_post` but I didn't get any email when the user add a new post and publish it. so it doesn't work. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try this hook instead of `publish_post`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/

Comment: @NilambarSharma same :(

Answer (score 0):

You use the `publish_post` hook. If `get_post_meta()` returns a value, it will trigger your actions to occur.

```
function run_on_post_publish( $post_id ) {
   $post_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'run_once', true );
   if ( ! empty( $post_data ) ) {
       return;
   }

   // Run the action you wish to occur when a post is published
    
    
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'run_once', true );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'run_on_post_publish' );
```

Comment: https://streamable.com/jhtzle i tried but it doesn't work. i don't know why.